# Object property is undefined when it comes from method parameter

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm stuck on this:

```js
var Names = function (name,integer) {
    this.name = name;
    this.integer = integer;
};

var Discount = {
    applyDiscount: function(person) {
        console.log("person name is: "    + person);            //Eve
        console.log("person integer is: " + person["integer"]); //undefined
        console.log("person integer is: " + Eve["integer"]);    // 23
    }
};

var Eve = new Names("Eve Something", 23);

Discount.applyDiscount("Eve");
```

When I try to get `Eve.integer` value (using `person` parameter) - I've get `undefined`.

Why `person["integer"]` isn't working in this case?

Comment: The usual JavaScript coding style is to reserve identifiers starting with capital letters for constructor functions. `Eve` should be `eve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the *string* `"Eve"` to the function and not the object that the variable `Eve` points to. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Oh, thanks. My mistake.
Need some rest :)

Comment: @user4217275 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Needed use Object, not a string:

```
Discount.applyDiscount(Eve);
```